# Minizinc: Need a brief description about each solver appeared in MiniZinc Configuration?

Tags: minizinc

I find several solvers appeared in MiniZinc Configuration. So what is the advantage of each solver? And what problems are classic examples for each soler? Thanks. [solvers in MiniZinc Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF3yb.png)

Answer (score 1):

All MiniZinc solvers known to the MiniZinc team, including those in the bundle, are described on the [software page](http://www.minizinc.org/software.html) of the MiniZinc website. Look for the heading "FlatZinc implementations".

Note that most of these solvers are full solving environment and that not all features of a solver might be natively available in the MiniZinc environment.